# How do I install correct NPM package when two packages have the same name?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-dynamodb, npm-install, loopbackjs

I'm trying to connect `Loopback3` to `DynamoDB`, and thus am looking to install a connector.  This one -- https://github.com/codecaptainadmin/loopback-connector-dynamodb/blob/master/README.md -- seemed good because it has instructions, as opposed to this one -- https://github.com/mandarzope/loopback-connector-dynamodb#readme.  But they both seem to have the same `NPM` name.  That is, the first says to:

`$ npm install loopback-connector-dynamodb --save`

but this seems to be installing the second one.  From my `package.json`:

```
    "loopback-connector-dynamodb": "0.1.0-5",
```

(0.1.0-5 is the version number of the one I don't want). How do I differentiate when I install the packages?

(On a parenthetical note, if someone recommends one over the other, or an entirely different package or manner to connect `Loopback3` to `DynamoDB`, I'd welcome the recommendation)

Comment: It doesn't seem like the one by `mandarzope` is published on NPM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question asked in your post is to prefix the package name with the relevant scope, e.g. `@letscomunica/loopback-connector-dynamodb` seems to be another path to the one you installed by `mandarzope`. You can find the scope by doing a search on [the NPM registry](https://www.npmjs.com/). See also the [npm docs on scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

However, your question points to a repository by `codecaptainadmin` which appears to not actually be published on NPM - I would think twice about using it if they're confused about how to do that and not accepting issues.

If you want one contained in the github repository belonging to `codecaptainadmin`, you can specify a git-sourced install like this: `npm install codecaptainadmin/loopback-connector-dynamodb`

Refer to the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for usage details on the above two formats.

Answer (score 3):

If you look here ( https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=loopback-connector-dynamodb ) you will see that loopback-connector-dynamodb package in npm repository references to https://github.com/mandarzope/loopback-connector-dynamodb repository.

If you run `npm docs loopback-connector-dynamodb`, you will be redirected to https://github.com/mandarzope/loopback-connector-dynamodb.

So I think that this package relates to mandarzope's repository.